# CSS - change parent's style upon hover, if it's child is of a specific class

Tags: css

I have multiple parent `DIV` elements, which has a child `SPAN` inside each of them.
The `CLASS` of the `SPAN` changes dynamically.

I have added `.parent:hover` to apply certain styles to it upon hover, but I wanted NO hover effect if it's child `SPAN` is of a specific `CLASS`

Example code:

```
.parent {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.parent:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #888888 inset;
}
.parent:hover .childActive {
    /* code that applies style to the child upon hover over the parent */
}
    /* need code that applies style to the parent upon hover, if childActive */
```

> I can do this by a roundabout solution by adding a class dynamically
>   to the parent whenever the child class changes to `childActive`

Is it possible to do this in pure css?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not a "parent" selector in CSS, but it has been discussed in a [number](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) of [places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). Other than with JS, i dont think you're going to get what you're after. If there was a parent selector you might do something like .parent:hover .childActive < .parent{ color:red; } but that would be super non-performant. Alternatively, you could apply classes to the child that "overlay" the parent's styles.. you'd have to supply your html and css to be sure though

Answer (score 0):

#### I definitely recommend simply adding the class to the parent instead, but here's a Javascript alternative.

With Javascript (ES5):

**1: Create two functions to invoke for when the cursor hovers and leaves the "parent" div (fired in event listener).**

This function adds class "active" to the "parent" div.

```
function parentHover(parent){
    if(parent.children[0].classList.contains('childActive')){
        parent.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

This function removes class "active" from the "parent" div.

```
function parentLeave(parent){
  parent.classList.remove('active');
}
```

**2: Create two event listeners for when hovering and leaving the parent div, passing through the functions created in step 1.**

```
var parentArray = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

parentArray.forEach(function(parent){
    parent.addEventListener('mouseover', parentHover(parent));
    parent.addEventListener('mouseout', parentLeave(parent));
}
```

**3: Add styles for class "active" when paired with class "parent"**

```
.parent.active{
  //certain styles
}
```